# How to have a piece of code continue to run throughout a function, while also allowing the other code to run?

Tags: python, multithreading, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico, thonny

My goal is when button A or B is pressed anytime throughout the whole function, it switches to a new process (screen).
I am currently trying to use threading, but it is not working, and I am honestly not sure how I can get my plan to work.

```
def buttonB():
    if button_b.read():
        clear()
        play()

def buttonA():
    clear()
    howToPlay()

#Creates Main Title Screens
def main():
    t1= _thread.start_new_thread(buttonB, ())
    # Creates Game Ttile Screen
    clear()
    display.set_pen(GREEN)
    display.text("Blink of an Eye", 30, 25, 240, 5)
    display.update()
    time.sleep(2)
    clear()
    screen = 1
    # Switches between two "screens" 
    while True:
        #How To play Title Screen
        if screen == 1:
            display.set_pen(YELLOW)
            display.text('''How To Play: Press 'A' ''', 15, 35, 240, 4)
            display.update()
            time.sleep(1)
            clear()
            screen = 2
        
        # Play Title Screen
        elif screen == 2:
            display.set_pen(MAGENTA)
            display.text('''Play: Press 'B' ''', 15, 35, 240, 4)
            display.update()
            time.sleep(1)
            clear()
            screen = 1
```

Please assist me on how I may write a piece of code that allows the code to constantly check in the function to see if button a or b is being pressed, and when it gets the hey, this button was pressed, the code no longer checks and it moves to another function.
I would also like to clarify that this code has other functions that use the same button for different reasons, so I only want it to work within the one function so it doesn't interfere with the other code. (I have the same problem for the rest of the code, but I thought I wouldn't add it because it is the same problem).

Answer (score 2):

You need three functions for this. One to check if button a was pressed.

```py
def is_button_a_pressed():
    return True
```

Another for checking if button b was pressed.

```py
def is_button_b_pressed():
    return False
```

I just returned True or False for these as I don't know how you check. Same effect, except I manually change it.

And finally one with a while-loop which constantly runs both of these functions until one of them succeeds (returns True).

```py
def check_buttons():
    global has_button_been_pressed
    while not has_button_been_pressed:
        if is_button_a_pressed():
            has_button_been_pressed = True
            how_to_play()

        if is_button_b_pressed():
            has_button_been_pressed = True
            play()
```

To implement these functions into your code, all you need to do is pass the `check_buttons` function into `_thread.start_new_thread` and you're done!

The "full" code might look something like this (obviously it's not actually the full code but it's the part you needed).

```py
has_button_been_pressed = False
def is_button_a_pressed():
    return True


def is_button_b_pressed():
    return False


def check_buttons():
    global has_button_been_pressed
    while not has_button_been_pressed:
        if is_button_a_pressed():
            has_button_been_pressed = True
            how_to_play()

        if is_button_b_pressed():
            has_button_been_pressed = True
            play()


def main():
    _thread.start_new_thread(check_buttons, ())
    # Creates Game Title Screen
    clear()
    display.set_pen(GREEN)
    display.text("Blink of an Eye", 30, 25, 240, 5)
    display.update()
    time.sleep(2)
    clear()
    screen = 1
    # Switches between two "screens" 
    while not has_button_been_pressed:
        if screen == 1:
            display.set_pen(YELLOW)
            display.text('''How To Play: Press 'A' ''', 15, 35, 240, 4)
            display.update()
            time.sleep(1)
            clear()
            screen = 2

            # Play Title Screen
        elif screen == 2:
            display.set_pen(MAGENTA)
            display.text('''Play: Press 'B' ''', 15, 35, 240, 4)
            display.update()
            time.sleep(1)
            clear()
            screen = 1
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It works! But it still goes back to the main function and plays the screens. Like when the button is pressed, it flashes the correct function but then goes back to the main function. 
(I added def is_button_a_pressed():
    if button_a.read():
        return True


def is_button_b_pressed():
    if button_b.read():
        return False)

Comment: I updated the code. Should work now!